# WinUSB error mounting Windows 10 on external hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, windows-10, winusb

I am trying to do dual boot here and when trying to create an external hard drive with Windows 10 bootable made my WinUSB gave the following error:

```
Installation failed !
Exit code: 256
Log:
Formatting device...
Wait 3 seconds for block device nodes to populate...
mkfs.fat: warning - lowercase labels might not work properly with DOS or Windows
mkfs.fat 4.0 (2016-05-06)
Mounting...
Copying...
Installing grub...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation complete. No error was reported.
Installing grub.cfg...
Exiting...
Syncing...
/usr/bin/winusb: line 78: 1148 Terminating while true; do
sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
done
Cleaning...
/usr/bin/winusb: line 78: 1294 Terminating while true; do
sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
done
Unmounting and removing '/media/winusb_iso_1478797225_29588'...
Unmounting and removing '/media/winusb_target_1478797225_29588'...
```

I already researched different WinUSB solutions and none worked, did not show that it failed, but when I boot the system through the USB it said the system was not found. Does anyone have any idea about the problem and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not boot from external drives. I think it is a way to keep people from using the same Windows license in more than one computer.

But you can install Ubuntu in an external drive or make a persistent live USB boot drive, and in Ubuntu install VirtualBox and in VirtualBox create install Windows 10. That way Windows will be in the same [virtual] machine all the time, even if the virtual machine is run on different hardware.

-o-

However, I think you are asking about another problem, and I think you are using the tool winusb to create a Windows install drive (in a USB stick). It seems there are problems with winusb and new versions of Ubuntu, so I added this feature to ***mkusb-nox***. See these links,

[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkusb version 7.5 - mkusb-nox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/v7#mkusb_version_7.5_-_mkusb-nox)

[Making a USB drive to install Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/v7#Making_a_USB_drive_to_install_Windows)

If you are willing to test a new version with a better user interface, but which is not yet tested much, and still in the unstable mkusb PPA, you can try according to the following link,

[dus - a revamped interface of mkusb and mkusb-nox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#dus_-_a_revamped_interface_of_mkusb_and_mkusb-nox)